# Mixed Integer Programming - How to model objective function with variables that depends on the solution?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming

I am modelling an optimization problem that is described as follows:

I would like to maximize audience for scheduling matches. There are *n* eligible teams and *n/2* different slots.
Teams will only play once.
The audience of each possible match is known.
Each slot has also a known audience reduction coefficient. To penalize audience for not being close to prime time.

Finally, in each slot you can schedule all the matches that you want knowing that the more matches scheduled in the same slot the more the audience is reduced. For example, 1 game in one slot the audience reduction is 0, for 2 games in one slot the reduction is 30%, an for 3 games in one slot the reduct is 50%...etc. This reduction applies to each match scheduled in the slot.

I am able to set-up objective function and all restrictions except for the last part of simulteaneity. I feel like it is needed to know in advance how much games are scheduled in each specific slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok not sure how you are taking your decision variables like is a game represented by variable $g$ or team set like $(t_i,t_j)$. Since main problem is to model the audience reduction, you may either model a binary variable $x_{g,s} =1$  if game $g$ is assigned to slot $s$ or an integer $x_{s}$
You may have a list or dictionary like $P=\{p_2,p_2,p_3,...\}$ where $p_k$ is the reduction penalty for assigning 1,2,3,... games in a slot.

$\sum_{k=1}^P kz_{k,s} = \sum_g x_{g,s} \ \ \forall s\in$ slots  (1)
or
$\sum_{k=1}^P kz_{k,s} = x_{s}$ if $x_{s}$ is an integer variable.  (2)

$ \sum_k z_{k,s} =1 \ \ \forall s$ where $z_{k,s}$ is a binary.  (3)

Then in the objective (if it's part of) use
$\sum_s\sum_kz_{k,s}p_k$ or for some other constraint use $\sum_kz_{k,s}p_k \ \ \forall s$

Comment: Sorry but I am not geting completley your explanation. I am using a binary decision variable that uses (team_i, team_j, slot), this is after used in objective function multiplied for audience of the specific match (also I added the other restrictions). But for the reduction of that audience I do not know if that should be added as new constraint or as a factor in the objective function. And also should I add a new integer decision variable that counts the number of matches per slot? Thanks!

Comment: Constrs (1) and (2) are either or. I have put in an or there. If your assignment is binary per game, per slot obviously you need to sum up the assignments per slot, so use (1) else use (2). That's because I don't know how you have modelled. Finally these constrs are for your the problem you've posted about- choosing the right penalty based on number of games per slot. Then upto you how you are using $z_{ks}$

Comment: Sorry but I dont get what represents in your example K Zks in expression (1). Could you please explain me? Thanks

Comment: Your penalties are in set $P=\{0.1,0.3,0.5,..\}$ corresponding to index$\{1,2,3,...\}$ which are same as number of games per slot. This variable can be binary if you have modelled like that or integer. So const(1) or it's integer equivalent (2) along with constr(3), helps to select the index $k$ using binary $z$ based on var $x$. If in a slot $x=2$ then $k=2$ and so $z_{2,s}=1$. Then using $z$ you can select $P_2$ as $z_{2,s}p_2$ will be selected as only $z_{2,s}=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think my problem is then related to my implementation using PulP.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what language you are using, your index may start from 0 as well.

Comment: I am using python (PulP library) the problem is I have trouble to index the penalties set when using as index the variable decision...

Comment: No, your index is just $k$ a routine python variable, not a decision var, like sum(k*z for k in P.index()) = x if you are using P as list or instead of P.index() simply P if P is dict like {0:0, 1:0.3,2:0.5}

Comment: Just if you have any feedback you can see my implementation here https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/mixed-integer-programming-problem-modelling-coincidence-restriction-in-schedul Thanks!